# Blank screen when turning on HDR in Windows

Tags: windows, hdr

When I turn on HDR in Windows control panel, the screen immediately becomes black and it still doesn't show anything after a few minutes. When I run games that support HDR, everything works fine. And when I connect another PC to the same monitor and enable HDR, everything works fine too.
Any ideas how to fix this problem?

Comment: Information missing : (1) How exactly do you turn on HDR? (2) When turned-on, is the screen blank whatever you do? (3) What are your computer model and Windows version? (4) Is the monitor external and what is it?

Comment: In addition to @harrymc (5) Which GPU do you use, and is your driver updated?

Comment: @harrymc the standard way - via the Windows control panel  2) yes 3) custom built PC, Windows 10 Pro 4) external, Innocn 27M2V

Comment: @1NN Zotac 3060 Ti and yes

Comment: @harrymc and by the way, how can it be not external if I connect another PC to it?

Comment: @user626528: Don't ask difficult question - that's my part...

Comment: When HDR is enabled or disabled, the display needs to be adapted. Evidently something goes wrong at this point. Is Windows fully updated (and which version)? Try also to test Windows integrity by running the commands [Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/7808-use-dism-repair-windows-10-image.html) and then [sfc /scannow](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2895-run-sfc-command-windows-10-a.html).

Comment: @harrymc nope this didn't change anything. Windows 10 22H2, all updated.

Comment: That nixes the easy solutions and leaves as likely some incompatibility between driver/monitor. Does turning off and on the monitor fix anything?

Comment: @harrymc no. Only the message that there is no signal.

Comment: Last idea : The monitor supports the USB-C, DisplayPort and HDMI interfaces. Which one are you using, and can you test another type of interface?

Comment: @harrymc yes it does work with DP. Strangely, the same HDMI cable worked for another PC.

Comment: What is your computer model and especially your CPU ?

Comment: @harrymc custom built, 7600X. Why?

Comment: Does the other PC which works fine have the same GPU ?

Comment: @harrymc no. The one that doesn't have this problem has integrated GPU.

Answer (score 0):

You could try doing **Ctrl + Windows + Shift + B** after enabling HDR and having the black screen, if the GPU's driver was successfully restarted you should hear a little beep noise.

You could also fully reinstalling your GPU drivers by:

- Fully remove your previous GPU drivers using [DDU](https://www.guru3d.com/download/display-driver-uninstaller-download/)
- Install the latest stable NVidia GPU drivers

If none were successful you could try another cable and/or another port on your GPU.
Last resort that would most likely work would be a full clean install on Windows...

Answer (score 0):

With HDR, you have a problem when connecting the monitor via HDMI.
Using DisplayPort, it works fine without a problem.

You have updated your graphical driver, your monitor doesn't seem to
have a firmware update, so as regarding software you have done the
maximum possible for an end-user.

You may still check whether your Windows 10 can be updated to version
23H2 (a small chance of it helping), or check for more updates to your
computer, such as for the BIOS/UEFI.

You may also check if your HDMI cable supports HDMI 2
(the higher the version the better), or try a higher-quality cable.

But if nothing helps, I would chalk it up to gods of incompatibility,
and keep on using DisplayPort.